# Related news block in taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to make a related news block on a term page instead of a node. I've done it on a node and it works fine, but when I try to do it on taxonomy term page it makes the whole block disappear.

This is what I have in the contextual filters and what I'm using as my relationship,
[image]

and here's whats in my taxonomy,
[image]

and this is what's in my content: nid[image]

and finally whats in my relationship.
[image]

Comment: Could you please identify any filters, fields,  and the path you used for the URL where this related block is used.

Comment: im not sure what you mean

Comment: At this point im trying to make the blocks I have not duplicate any of the nodes on the existing page. Everything else seems to work ok

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the block disappears because no content is returned by the view. You're filtering for both a taxonomy term id and a node id, while only a taxonomy term is present in the url of a taxonomy term page. Since there are no nodes that match the criterium 'no nid' there are no results. I believe this should work if you use only the taxonomy contextual filter. (This is if I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do).

Comment: when i only use the taxonomy contextual filter, i get results but its the same ones that are already displaying on the term page, thats why i was using a relationship to try to keep it from displaying the same nodes in the blocks

Comment: Ah I see. But do you want the result to be the other terms that are present on the nodes of that term page, or nodes with those other terms? (I'm afraid I don't know how in both cases)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you have a relationship to do that, you would have to add another relationship to get the term id's node's taxonomy term's nodes. This will be quite a bit of joins and it might be easier to write some SQL first.